# Identificação de cor python

Tags: python, python-requests

Bom preciso de um programa que identifique a cor de cima e clique na cor respectiva em baixo , tentei pelo uso de imagem mas a cor de cima ela muda os tons geralmente,não tem um padrão.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
import pyautogui
rosac = 'rosac.png'
rosa1 = 'rosa1.png'
roxoc = 'roxoc.png'
roxo1 = 'roxo1.png'
amc = 'amc.png'
am1 = 'am1.png'
pc = 'pc.png'
p1 = 'p1.png'


if pyautogui.locateOnScreen(rosac):
    pyautogui.click(rosa1)
elif pyautogui.locateOnScreen(roxoc):
        pyautogui.click(roxo1)
elif pyautogui.locateOnScreen(amc):
            pyautogui.click(am1)
elif pyautogui.locateOnScreen(pc):
            pyautogui.click(p1)
```

Comment: Essa pergunta é repetida. Queira seguir as orientações dadas no espaço de comentários na primeira vez que perguntou, e editar aquela postagem para elaborar melhor. Para evitar informação espalhada em 2 lugares, está desativado o espaço de comentários desta versão duplicada, se alguém precisar, utilize o campo apropriado da [postagem original](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/553317/70).